# is it possible to close answers as "primarily opinionated"?

Tags: discussion, answers

I feel that some answers that get upvoted are very opinionated. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194828/using-dynamic-memory-in-the-proper-scope) question contains the sentence:

> Using new and delete expressly has few uses in modern C++ short of
>   writing custom containers, allocators, and other lower-level tasks.

Comment: you can't close an answer, you can only close a question. if you have objections about an answer, you can comment and vote. if others see your comment, they might agree and vote up your comment and potentially down vote the question if they agree with you.

Comment: What would "closing an answer" *mean* anyway?

Answer (score 12):

No, individual answers can't be closed. That's what downvotes and comments are for. You can vote to close the question as "primarily opinion based" if it's generating nothing but opinionated answers.

Answer (score 7):

Answers that express opinions are fine and even desirable, if it is an expert opinion, backed by experience.

That particular opinion you quoted enjoys wide consensus among C++ experts, there's no reason to penalize an answer for containing it.