# To which extent can we add opinionated commentary to an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I want to edit an answer I wrote a while ago and am finding myself also wanting to add commentary based on my experience with the technology in the years since writing the answer.

To which extent can I do that?

I think I know the domain with acceptable authority for the things I want to say, and I add it because I feel it supports the method described in my answer.

However, it is quite close to being an opinion, and I think the consensus is we should avoid this? Can we not be opinionated in answers?

[This discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351303/what-action-should-be-taken-on-an-answer-making-opinionated-statements-about-the) is about being opinionated in answers but I don't think it applies here, as I would rather justify a solution than simply rant about something.

Comment: The site has rules about _asking_ for opinions in questions, not about _offering_ opinions in answers. The problem with the answer in the linked meta post is not that it includes opinions, is that it doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Also closely related: [*is it possible to close answers as “primarily opinionated”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298509/2751851) Quoting [Ben Voigt's answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298533/2751851): "Answers that express opinions are fine and even desirable, if it is an expert opinion, backed by experience."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding your opinion about the approach shown in the answer is fine as long as the post actually contains a concrete and verifiable answer.

Note that "commentary based on my experience with *the technology*" sounds like you plan to comment on whole language/framework/platform - it may mean that question was way too broad or asking for recommendations - should be closed instead. If the question is scoped properly commentary on the broader scope would be better done in a personal blog/other media.